# broadcom 4312 card. cant find any wireless network

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom

I switched my computer over to Ubuntu from Windows, big mistake. I cant get my wireless to work. I scan wlan0 and a bunch of other things that I copied and pasted from the internet. I have no idea if my wireless card is working or not? I tried to manually create the connection by typing in my routers `ssid` and `wpa2` key, the little wireless icon in the upper right looked like it was looking for the router.

No matter what I scan for in the terminal I get interface does not support scanning.
any advice?

Edit for grimpitch:

```
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at f69fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
Capabilities: [e8] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 07-cf-5f-ff-ff-62-00-22
Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

output from iwconfig:
eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

lspci:
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at f69fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: wl

thanks grimpitch.  your help and a youtube video showing me that i had to change bios on my model dell after switching to linux got it.

Comment: Get to software sources, additional drivers tab. Can you see and activate the driver there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the firmware for this type of card.

Execute in a terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Comment: thank you grimpitch.  i appreciate your help but i have done that several times today.  when i do that ubuntu says"firmware-b43-lpphy-installer is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded."

Comment: Run a `sudo lspci -nnv` and paste in the info block about the wifi card to your original post.

Comment: I just need those few lines about the Broadcom card.

Comment: Let's install the following packages: `bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-dkms`

Comment: eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth1      No scan results

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
still cant connect

Comment: Do a reboot, and see what `iwconfig` tells you about the interfaces, also check again with `lspci -nnv` and see whether the kernel driver is `wl`